# É possível trocar a função click para outro tipo de função?

Tags: javascript, signalr

Segue o código:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
connection.start().done(function() {
    // Wire up Send button to call NewContosoChatMessage on the server.
    $('#newContosoChatMessage').click(function () { // <----------AQUI
        contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
        $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
    });
```

Só não quero a função `click` para executar essa linha abaixo:

`contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());`

Existe outra forma de executar a linha acima sem usar a função click ?

Documento SignalR: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function () {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
    contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function (name, message) {
        console.log(name + ' ' + message);
    });
    connection.start().done(function () {
        $('#newContosoChatMessage').click(function () { // <----------AQUI
            contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Se não é no `click`, em que momento deseja? Existem várias formas

Comment: Cara qualquer coisa !!!, menos a função click. Pode ser uma função simples de `myFunction`. Já tentei de tudo, não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia isolar em outra função:

```
function invoke(){
    contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
}
```

E invocar em `done`:

```
connection.start().done(function() {
   invoke();
});
```

No `ready` do jQuery (não testado):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function invoke(){
        contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
    }

    connection.start().done(function() {
       invoke();
    });
});
```

Comment: Valeu funcionou aqui

Comment: Lucas digamos que o código está dentro de uma função `ready`. Será que é possivel chamar `invoke();` ?

Comment: `ready` do jQuery? Se for nenhum problema @MatheusMiranda

Comment: Sim, atualizei post, favor olhar.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @MatheusMiranda

Answer (score 1):

Podes alterar para outro evento sim, sem problemas acredito.

Exemplo :

```
$('#newContosoChatMessage').focusin(function () { //Foco no elemento
$('#newContosoChatMessage').blur(function () { //Saindo do foco do elemento
```